# How to install mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake at Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, pacman, pacman-package-manager

Per this URL, https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake, I use the command as follows to install  mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake. It complains Unable to locate package mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake

sudo pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake

Comment: Hey did you end up finding a solution for this?